# pip3 gone after hombrew upgrade

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I upgraded my outdated packages with `brew upgrade`, but now I find that the `pip3` command (pip for Python 3) that I previously had is gone. My Python 3.6 installation is still there:

```
cls@clsmba > python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

`>pip` points to pip for Python 2.7:

```
cls@clsmba ~> pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

cls@clsmba ~> pip2 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

`pip3.5` seems to be a leftover from an older Python 3 version:

```
cls@clsmba ~> pip3.5
Failed to execute process '/usr/local/bin/pip3.5'. Reason:
The file '/usr/local/bin/pip3.5' specified the interpreter '/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5', which is not an executable command.
```

I tried using [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to get the command back, but that didn't work:

```
cls@clsmba ~> python3 get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

What can I do now to get the command back in a clean way?

Reinstalling with `brew reinstall python` did not install pip. Also, note the error message:

```
cls@clsmba > brew reinstall python
==> Reinstalling python 
==> Installing dependencies for python: sqlite
==> Installing python dependency: sqlite
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/sqlite-3.23.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/75/75bf05c73a9b51101ea166742eb9baf285eda857fd98ea1d50a3abf0d81bd978?__gda__=exp=1523530592~hmac=ae4fc4056ff461c4fc3ca75983cd0f22c231e084312090e6c484aa59b02d3c1f&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sqlite-3.23.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz%22&response-content-type=application%2Fgzip&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX1-3IGgcJJtJX59zX8HP5dbhO9NFlYr07n9KOgP7AOcaoTM4pAOrLWqfH9MzbvCoUoNWKvWGRelKsrku6Kulv8WBBKAT7jGnTKBaYlEQpp1oEnHgh5nU-WVdBxk
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring sqlite-3.23.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides an older sqlite3.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/pkgconfig

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.23.1: 11 files, 3MB
==> Installing python
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python-3.6.5.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cls/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-3.6.5.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-3.6.5.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin --install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt
Last 15 lines from /Users/cls/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python/post_install.01.python3:
copying setuptools/script (dev).tmpl -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/script.tmpl -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/cli-32.exe -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/cli-64.exe -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/cli.exe -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/gui-32.exe -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/gui-64.exe -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/gui.exe -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/command/launcher manifest.xml -> build/lib/setuptools/command
running install_lib
copying build/lib/easy_install.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
copying build/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
error: could not delete '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py': Permission denied
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall python`
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

If you need Homebrew's Python 2.7 run
  brew install python@2

Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them run
  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Summary
```

Prepending to the PATH acoording to @Mark Setchell's answer does not seem to change things:

```
  bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/opt/python/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/share/python3:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Library/TeX/texbin
    bash-3.2$ python
    Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> ^D
    bas

h-3.2$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
bash-3.2$ pip3
bash: pip3: command not found
bash-3.2$ pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: You can pass `--ignore-installed` and/or `-U` to `get-pip.py` to force reinstallation.

Comment: No error, but still no `pip3` command.

Comment: Try running `type pip3`  and `type python` etc to see what points to what and whether you have any aliases set up which may confuse things - note that `which pip3` is not as useful as `type pip3` etc.

Comment: You appear to also have **homebrew**'s Python2 installed, as well as Apple's Python2 and **homebrew**'s Python3.

Comment: That is true, but I'm not sure that I can safely remove the 2s . I'm not aware of any aliases. I think the main issue is that there is just no pip in  `/usr/local/opt/python/bin`

Comment: YMMV, but I would be tempted to make a backup, remove **homebrew** Python, Python3, Python2, Python@2, Python@3 et al. Then run `brew doctor` till you get a clean bill of health, then just install the one you want.

Comment: @MarkSetchell As far as I know, on a clean system, it shouldn't pose a problem to have Homebrew's Python 2 and Python 3 and Apple's default Python 2 installed. Homebrew explicitly supports such a setup.

Comment: @anothernode Yes, agreed. I suspect the OP's system is somehow not quite clean though... and working out what's wrong with it is maybe harder than starting from clean... If you have other approaches to suggest, then feel free to go for it... I'm always happy to learn too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide how you want it to work and **homebrew** can then accommodate you. The information is available if you run:

```
brew info python
```

> Python has been installed as   /usr/local/bin/python3
>
> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
>   `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been
>   installed into   /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
>
> If you need Homebrew's Python 2.7 run   brew install python@2
>
> Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them run
>   pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
>
> You can install Python packages with   pip3 install  They
>   will install into the site-package directory
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

---

So:

- if you want to use **versioned** commands, i.e `python3`, `pip3` and `idle3`, put `/usr/local/opt/python/bin` at the start of your PATH:

  `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/bin:$PATH`
- if you want to use **un-versioned** commands to mean Python3 and its tools, i.e.`python`, `pip` and `idle`, put `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` at the start of your PATH:

  `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH`
- if you want to use the (ancient) Python v2.7 supplied by Apple as part of macOS, put `/usr/bin` at the start of your PATH, and use the command `python`:

  `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Good to know how it is supposed to work. However, that is not the case on my system right now (see edits)

Comment: There is no pip here: `cls@clsmba > ls /usr/local/opt/python/bin
2to3              2to3-3.6          idle3             idle3.6           pydoc3            pydoc3.6          python3           python3-config    python3.6         python3.6-config  python3.6m        python3.6m-config pyvenv            pyvenv-3.6`

Answer (score 1):

They changed the default commands in the Homebrew package for Python 3 to be `python3` and `pip3` to be compliant with [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

If `pip3` doesn't work I'd try reinstalling Python: `brew reinstall python`.

`brew install python` installs Python 3 (and `pip`) since [Homebrew 1.6.0](https://brew.sh/2018/04/09/homebrew-1.6.0/).

---

The error in the output for `brew reinstall python` that you posted says that `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init.py__` cannot be deleted because of lacking permissions.

Have you checked the permissions of that file and verified that you have write permissions on it?

If not, you can add write permissions with

```
chmod u+w /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init.py
```

and then try again.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there's something wrong. I don't get that `...could not delete...` error for `brew reinstall python` on my machine. Maybe try `brew uninstall --force python` and then install again?

Comment: Maybe `brew doctor` can provide a hint on what’s going wrong with the installation?

Comment: I'm looking at `brew doctor` - there is nothing that is obviously connected to the issue, but I'll try to fix each one so that homebrew doesn't get confused