# When I type 'python -V' in my terminal...why do I see Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, bash, macos, conda

I have only installed Python3.6 on my Mac. 
I have also installed miniconda. 
Whether I run the command:

$python -V

in my home directory, or a specific project directory, the output is Python 2.7.10. Why isn't it Python 3.6, and how can I change this default?

Comment: On a unix-based system with python2.x installed by default, invoking `python [args]` (in this case `[args]` is `-V`) will always use the default-installed version of python. Since you installed Python 3, assuming the installation added python3 to your `$PATH` environment variable, you should be able to use `python3 -V` and it should return `3.6.x`

Comment: run  $python3 -V

Comment: Thank you all! That makes sense. Python3 -V showed the correct thing.

Comment: Run `which python`

Comment: *You* only installed Python 3.6, but your Mac *came* with Python 2.7 preinstalled.

Comment: I think it is pretty well explained here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795421/2836621

Answer (score 2):

Probably what happened is that you have 2 versions of Python in your environment:

- 3.6 that you installed manually
- 2.7.10 installed by miniconda

For some reason the environment variable for the python command is set to the 2.7.10 one, so in your shell the python command refers to the 2.7 version, if you want it to point to the 3.6 one you need to update the path variable for the python command.

If you want to manage more environments i suggest you to use Anaconda/miniconda and setting up virtual environments for both python 2 and 3, so you can switch between the two.

If you are only interested in one version of python either use a conda distribution or plain Python, as mixing things often creates this kind of problems.

More info on managing virutal environments:

Python: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Anaconda: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Answer (score 2):

Really it depends on the system what the behavior is. See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) for more, but roughly speaking,

- `python2` should always point you to Python 2.x
- `python3` should always point you to Python 3.x
- `python` on most distributions today will point to Python 2.x
- Except on a few, it points to Python 3.x now
- And on a given system `python` might be overridden to point to Python 3.x
- And in a virtualenv / venv, `python` can point to either, depending how it was set up

So in other words, if you want to not really worry about it, use `python2` and `python3` commands instead of `python`.

Although, macOS violates this pattern by installing `python` without a `python2` link (there is a `python2.7` link, though).