# Python 3.6 still the python version the system reports after installing and upgrading with homebrew to 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

**Prefix**

I will try and keep this short while providing some context.

I am new to programming and I am writing apps with Django and deploying them to Heroku. Heroku provides the following recommendation when I push.

> The latest version of Python 3.6 is python-3.6.6 (you are using python-3.6.4, which is unsupported).
>   remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.6).

Therefore I thought it was best to update my Macs python 3 install using Homebrew. I used Homebrew for the original install.

**Main issue**

I have installed Python 3.7 using Homebrew but when I check my systems version it tells me it is python 3.6.4

> $ python3 --version
>
> Python 3.6.4

However when I check the version in Homebrew it is 3.7

> $ brew info python
>
> python: stable 3.7.0 (bottled)

Why isn't the update registering for the main python version?

**Further questions and confusion**

In all of my projects virtual environments the python is still V3.6. Is there a way to upgrade within the virtual env to V3.7 or do I have to create a new virtual env?

Also when I run

> brew doctor

I get the following

> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
>   `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
>   software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
>   compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
>   script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
>   .  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m-config
>   .  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3-config
>   .  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6-config
>   .  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
>   .   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
>   .  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config

From my understanding these are system python files and shouldn't be touched.

Will these cause any issues with my homebrew install?

Are these responsible for my system saying the python version is 3.6?

**Please let me know if you need further information. Thanks in advance for any help!**

Comment: From your post looks like using the command `python3 --version` is mapped to the 3.6.4 install. While python 3.7 may be installed, it might not be mapped correctly to `python3`.  It's simply not enough to install python and expect the system to update itself accordingly.  You will have to map the command to the python version you wish to use.  You may find this useful: https://weknowinc.com/blog/running-multiple-python-versions-mac-osx

Comment: I explained it pretty clearly here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795421/2836621

Comment: The differences between 3.6.4 and 3.6.6 probably don't matter to you at all.  I suggest simply continuing with 3.6.4 which you already have.

Comment: Have you tried `python3.7` command?

Comment: @TheSidhantGoyal I haven't sorry, I've since changed my environments a lot and I don't use Heroku anymore. I think editing my PATH would have solved the issue but I can't confirm at the moment.