# installed python 3x on mac but terminal still show version still 2x

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

I installed python 3x via home brew, the process was successful.

However when I check version, it shows 2x

here is the terminal output

```
➜  ~ brew install python
Warning: python 3.7.2 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link python` to link this version.
➜  ~ brew link python
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
➜  ~ sudo brew link python
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
➜  ~ python -V 
Python 2.7.10
```

I think I need to modify some kind of path. And do some magic then pray...lol

Anyway anyone know how to get this work on my machine? I'm mac latest

Comment: What is the output of `python3 -V` ?

Comment: It's all explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795421/2836621

Answer (score 1):

First, solve your permission problem by running the official command from the [Homebrew Documentation, Troubleshooting page](https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting)

```
cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var opt Cellar Caskroom Frameworks
```

Then run  `brew link python`

And finally run `echo $PATH` and check that your `/usr/local/bin` has precedence over other directories.

Answer (score 0):

you could do `brew uninstall python3` and install it from the python website here https://www.python.org/

When you go install a module you do `pip3 install packageName`
And when you run a program you could run it from your IDE (I recommend VSCode) or run it from the terminal with `python3 drag_python_file_here`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `python3` instead of python on Mac so like `python3 path/to/file.py` and `pip` is now `pip3` so like `pip3 install pillow`