# Python is saying that a module has not been installed when it is installed

Tags: python, macos

whenever I try to run a python script that uses a module it says that the module has not been installed and if you try to install it it says it has been installed already I think it is trying to use python 2.7 when it should be using python 3.7 but I do not know how to make it use python 3.7 I am on a mac and I am not using homebrew

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795421/2836621

Answer (score 1):

**Homebrew version after 1.5 -**

According to the [official Homebrew page](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/):

*On 1st March 2018 the python formula will be upgraded to Python 3.x and a python@2 formula will be added for installing Python 2.7 (although this will be keg-only so neither python nor python2 will be added to the PATH by default without a manual brew link --force). We will maintain python2, python3 and python@3 aliases.*

So to install Python 3, run the following command:

```
brew install python3
```

Then, the `pip` or `pip3` is installed automatically, and you can install any package by `pip install <package>` or `pip3 install <package>`for python 3 packages.

So if you are running older python 2 script, install required packages and run as below :

```
pip install <package>

python <script.py>
```

If you wish to run python 3 script, install required packages and run as below :

```
pip3 install <package>

python3 <script.py>
```

All relevant packages will get installed as per the required environment and help run the script.

Comment: I am not using homebrew I used the installer from Pythons web page. do you know a way of fixing this without using homebrew?

Comment: Assuming you have installed Python 3 from their official website, run `pip3 install <package>` instead of `pip install <package>` to clear versioned dependencies and then run your script with `python3 <script.py>` from the relevant directory where your file is present. Let me know if this helps as regardless of where you installed python from, this should work the same.